# Construct a struct that holds a generic iterator of i32 from 'from_iter'?

Tags: rust

I wonder if you can create a struct containing a generic iterator (say of i32) from `from_iter`.

I tried [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe4aa7c0e815e88af62538653ac66803):

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;

struct IntIterator<T: Iterator<Item = i32>> {
    iter: T,
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = i32>> FromIterator<i32> for IntIterator<T> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = i32>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        IntIterator {
            iter: iter.into_iter(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = i32>> Iterator for IntIterator<T> {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let int_iter: IntIterator<_> = vec.into_iter().collect();
    for i in int_iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

but it says 'mismatched types':

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
7  | impl<T: Iterator<Item = i32>> FromIterator<i32> for IntIterator<T> {
   |      - this type parameter
...
10 |             iter: iter.into_iter(),
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
             found associated type `<I as IntoIterator>::IntoIter`
   = note: you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:25:52
   |
25 |     let int_iter: IntIterator<_> = vec.into_iter().collect();
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `B` declared on the associated function `collect`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
25 |     let int_iter: IntIterator<_> = vec.into_iter().collect::<IntIterator<_>>();
   |                                                           ++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is impossible. The return type of `from_iter()` needs to depend on its generic parameter, but the return type is `Self`, and it is already defined before the method and its generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`FromIterator` is usually used to make something that consumes the iterator. It's probably better to implement `From` [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d07f8a18f468f4c3ba8ed8e8d258f975).

```rs
impl<T, I> From<T> for IntIterator<I>
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = i32, IntoIter = I>,
{
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        IntIterator {
            iter: value.into_iter(),
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to call `into_iter` on the `Vec` since you're implementing it for `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`.

Alternatively, you can make an extension trait (this time on `Iterator` but should work similarly if you want it on `IntoIterator`) [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08c23c9c536cfc4a0277913dc1d6f176).

```rs
trait ToIntIter: Iterator<Item = i32> + Sized {
    fn to_int_iter(self) -> IntIterator<Self> {
        IntIterator {
            iter: self
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = i32>> ToIntIter for T {}
```